# A model and undefined terms.

Tags: geometry

Axiomatic system consists of undefined terms, postulates, theorems and definitions. When finding a model for geometry we “select something” for the undefined term LINE and the resulting model could be Euclidean of spherical (or other) geometry depending on which parallel postulate we are working with.

My question: by “selecting something” exactly what are we doing, are we defining the undefined term LINE or are we doing something else?

Comment: I believe the technical term is "interpreting", not "defining." You are assigning a specific meaning to the undefined term "LINE", and verifying that this meaning satisfies the postulates that you need to meet. The Axiomatic System is syntactic, while the model is semantic.